# Accessing nested YAML with different keys with jinja2

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Rendering jinja template with non-uniform nested dictionary mapping is failing. Error is always related to 'dict object' has no attribute <'some key'>.

```
{% for rule in INPUT %}
   {{ rule }}
   {{ INPUT[rule].target }}
{% endfor %}
```

```
INPUT:
   rule1:
     src: 1.1.1.1
     target: ACCEPT
   rule2:
     inintf: eth0
FORWARD:
   rule4:
     outintf: br-6b
```

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'target'"}
```

If the yaml file is like below then it works.

```
INPUT:
   rule1:
     src: 1.1.1.1
     target: ACCEPT
   rule2:
     inintf: eth0
     target: ACCEPT
FORWARD:
   rule4:
     target: DOCKERN
     outintf: br-6b
```

Is there any way to make it work with non-uniform dictionary mappings?

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected ']'

is the result of unbalanced brackets

```
-A INPUT -d {{ INPUT[rules].dest] }}
```

Comment: Corrected and also simplified the rules.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use [iptables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iptables_module.html) module?

Comment: iptables doesn't suit my needs as I have to do rule parsing before applying it to the node.